# Error in SQL syntax for Prepared Statement?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to run a prepare statement and get an error in MySQL syntax. Not sure what is the error?

Code:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
conn = ds.getConnection();
String query = "select distinct FName  from PRL p1, RequestView p2 where p1.RequestId = p2.RequestId and p1.PackageId = p2.PackageId and p1.ProductId = ? and p1.ProductNumber = ?  and p1.Version = ?  order by p2.ArtName";
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1,id);
stmt.setString(2,num);
stmt.setString(3,ver);
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? and p1.ESTProductMatNumber =?  and p1.Version =?  order by p2.ArtworkName' at line 1 
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I figured it out. rs = stmt.executeQuery(query); has to be rs = stmt.executeQuery();

Comment: You were executing the query with the query as one of the values, presumably.

Comment: BTW if you use Java 7+, consider using autocloseable feature like this:

    try (stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
        stmt.setString(1,id);
        stmt.setString(2,num);
        stmt.setString(3,ver);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);        
        ...
    } // use catch if you want to deal with it